# Issue with using JSON.stringify after using jQuery.map

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web-scraping

I am writing a bookmarklet (that will eventually be a plugin) to scrape web pages for list items in jQuery under a specified div. I'm having an issue with using `JSON.stringify`

The following code allows me to convert each individual item to JSON, but has issues when using `join` to concatenate each string.

```
var dMap = $("div").filter($("#<div-id>")).find("li").map(function() {
    var iObject = {
        id: $(this).data('id'),
        text: $(this).text(),
        list_name: $(this).closest('div').attr('id')
    };
    return JSON.stringify(iObject);
});
console.log(dMap);
```

This second snippet of code creates each object in the array correctly, but the resulting array doesn't log the resulting JSON.

```
var dMap = $("div").filter($("#,div-id.")).find("li").map(function() {
    return {
        id: $(this).data('id'),
        text: $(this).text(),
        list_name: $(this).closest('div').attr('id')
    };
});
console.log(dMap);
var json = JSON.stringify(dMap);
console.log(json);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: As we can't see what `console.log` outputs, can you put the output in the question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the documentation for [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

> As the return value is a jQuery-wrapped array, it's very common to get() the returned object to work with a basic array.

Have you tried:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(dMap.get());
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! It's always the small things you miss. :D